# triggering an onchange event of a select box

Tags: javascript

I have a select box, which i can populate using two methods.

First - Just by selecting any one of the option in the select box.

Second - I have a link just beside the select box.Clicking this link takes me to a page2, which has the same options but as links in page2.When i click one of them , it populates the select box.

Selecting the option directly from the "select" triggers an onchange event in it.
But when i click the link, select my required option from that page, it does not trigger the onchange event in the select box.
I am not sure where i am doing a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you post your code we might be able to help. Otherwise it is just jeopardy...

Comment: i try to voteup but i dont have enough points to do that.thanks for your advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the onchange is fired only when user does selection.

There's an easy workaround... have the JS code which populates the select box call the same JS code that is called from onchange trigger of the select.

Comment: @swathi - if you like the answer, it would be appreciated if you could up-vote it as well (up-arrow next to the answer). Cheers :)